Godot: detect what the Mouse is holding (file from OS file system) while hovering over Godot window
in Godot, is it possible to check for what what the user currently is holding with the mouse (for example an *.mp4 file from the OS file system) while hovering the cursor over the application/game window?
I want to create an application using Godot 4.2.2 with GDScript and I'm adding the functionality for dropping files on the application window using the files_dropped function. So far it works: it returns me the file location in my file system.
But while the user is holding a file over the appliction window, I want to show where that file can be dropped. I will have several list items (Nodes/scenes in a VBoxContainer) and I want to give the option to drop the file either before, between or after any items in that list.
Just for context
Once a video gets dropped on the application, Godot will get the file path, and give that to a python script executed by python in a virtual environment. In this I installed PyAV (ffmpeg) to get the metadata of the video, which then is put in a json file. Godot then reads that json file and displays the information in the GUI.
I know that I probably could have used some kind of plugin for Godot to get the video metadata, but I also want to generate a PDF, and for Godot I didn't find a good solution. So Python it is.
What I tried so far
I wasn't able to try anything regarding this issue in Godot, because I couldn't find any function to detect what the mouse is holding.
Before I was trying Python with flet, kivy and kivyMD, but those are partially more limited regarding their funktionality. I find that kind of surprising, since GUI is all they're doing.
I also tried PySide/PyQt, but I think those are unnecessarily complicated, so now I'm back using Godot for this.

I don't have a specific solution but I suspect you will need to observe the OS drag event with a separate program (C# or Python for example) and then either notify a listener inside Godot using a socket or have Godot observe a file which is being written to by the other script which is periodically updated with structured information about the file being dragged.
